Is it possible to add shortcutes to VSCode"Resolve Save Conflict" editor?
When a file is edited both in vscode and externally, a "Resolve Save Conflict" editor pops up.
This is great, but is there any way to add keyboard shortcuts to the common merge actions (Next difference, previous difference, copy selection/current difference from the left side to the right side, etc)?
Currently, it seems like it's a manual scroll and then you need to click the right arrow in the middle, which can be time-consuming if there are many differences.
I tried googling and looking through actions and keybindings, but couldn't find anything.
